# Not able to update database column with multiple values inside for loop

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update database based on `user input`:

```
# user input : 
val = [[2, 'Yes'], [11, 'No'], [12, 'Yes']]
# Code : 
if val is not None: 
    for a in val:
            Model.objects.filter(id=a[0]).update(value=str(a[1]))
        return Response({"Success":"Updated"}, status= status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
else: 
    return Response({"Error":"Updation Not Required"}, status=status.HTTP_417_EXPECTATION_FAILED)
```

Problem I'm facing is, the above code only updates single record (first record) in database, not updating remaining records([11, 'No'], [12, 'Yes']).

Comment: Are you sure `val` is a list of lists?  If coming from browser, it may be a string: "[[2, 'Yes'], [11, 'No'], [12, 'Yes']]".  You may need to use `val = json.loads(val)`

Comment: val is list only.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is nested in the loop so it doesn't complete.

Try:

```
for a in val:
    Model.objects.filter(id=a[0]).update(value=str(a[1]))
return Response({"Success":"Updated"}, status= status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

**UPDATE:**

To diagnose:

```
for a in val:
    print(a, a[0], a[1])
    entity = Model.objects.get(id=a[0])
    print('entity:')
    print(entity)
    print('entity.value:')
    print(entity.value)

return Response({"Just Testing":"Yes"}, status= status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

also:

```
for a in val:
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(id=a[0])
    print([p.value for p in queryset])

return Response({"Just testing":"Yes"}, status= status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

Comment: the code that you pasted am using it , while copy pasting might be a space issue. Loop is woring fine.

Comment: [[2, 'Yes'], [11, 'No'], [12, 'Yes']]
<class 'list'>
[2, 'Yes']
2
Yes
[11, 'No']
11
No
[12, 'Yes']
12
Yes

Comment: can you suggest , why only one value(first one) is updating in database, any other methods should i try to update those values inside db

Comment: Do they exist already in database?  What are their current values?  I will update answer

Comment: yes, columns exist in db , [2 --> id(already present), yes --> value of the column need to be updated]

Comment: output from diagonse 1:                                                                                                                  [[2, 'Yes'], [11, 'No'], [12, 'Yes']]
<class 'list'>
AIW_Model_Predictions object (2)
Yes
AIW_Model_Predictions object (11)
No
AIW_Model_Predictions object (12)
Yes

Comment: can you suggest how to save the value to database ? (considering diagonse : 1)

Comment: Sorry, having a hard time parsing.  Can you add the output as code in your question, so I can see the line breaks?  I added more to diagnosis 1, so please use that.

Comment: So, the reason they don't update is that they already have those values.  `id=12` already is `Yes`.  Change to: `val = [[2, 'Maybe'], [11, 'Foo'], [12, 'Bar']]` and see what happens

Comment: you are getting it wrong , Yes/No value will be passed by user & those values will update db , currently value column in db is blank.

Comment: No.  In diagnose 1, we are querying the database.  It is not blank.

Comment: [2, 'Yes'], [11, 'No'], [12, 'Yes']]
<class 'list'>
Model object (2)
entity.value: 

Model object (11)
entity.value: 

Model object (12)
entity.value: 

Entity value blank , apologies earlier there were some wrong entries due to testing

Comment: thank you for all your responses, your print(entity.value) trick helped me to solve my problem, now db is updating :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if val is not None: 
    for a in val:
        entity = Model.objects.get(prediction=a[0])
        entity.value = a[1]
        entity.save(update_fields=['value'])
    return Response({"Success":"Updated"}, status= status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
else: 
    return Response({"Error":"Updation Not Required"}, status=status.HTTP_417_EXPECTATION_FAILED)
```

Comment: entity = Model.objects.get(prediction=a[0]) will be --> entity = Model.objects.get(id=a[0])